# In EF-CF is it possible to fetch once then hold in memory?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a property `LeadTypeID` that I want EF to fetch if null, and then hold in memory for the life cycle of the application. Is there a built in way I can do this or perhaps someone has a suggestion? Thanks

```
Public Class Lead
    Public Property LeadID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property LeadTypeID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property LeadType As LeadType
End Class

Public Class LeadType
    Public Property LeadTypeID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property LastUpdated As Date
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no built in way (although your Lead entity will stay in the local graph for the lifetime of the context, its not a good idea to keep a context for the life of an application).

Personally I solve this problem using dependency injection and a little cache object. The following is an example of how I cache an entire table (with write-thru caching), caching a single integer is even simpler, inject/create the context in the constructor, set the value as a public property, and bind it in singleton scope.

The cache objects:
https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog/blob/master/Blog/Data/Entities/Blog/CachedBlogRepository.cs

The binding:
https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog/blob/master/Blog/Data/PersistanceModule.cs